# Proof of power series uniform convergence on compact set

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

I proved:

If a power series converges pointwise on a compact set then it converges uniformly.

Please could somebody check my proof?

My idea is to use Abel's theorem:

Let $g(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n x^n$ be a power series that converges at the point $x=R > 0$. Then the series converges uniformly on $[0,R]$. A similar result holds for $x=-R$.

Let $K$ be a compact set. Let $M = \max K, m = \min K$. Let $p(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n x^n$ be pointwise convergent on $K$.

If $m < 0 < M$ then by Abel's theorem $p$ converges uniformly on $[0,M]$ and by the negative case uniformly on $[m,0]$ therefore uniformly on $K \subseteq [m,M]$. The argument is similar if $0 < m < M$ or $m < M < 0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proof is correct. Presentation may be improved by preceding it with a lemma: if a series converges uniformly on each of the sets $E_1,\dots,E_m$, then it converges uniformly on $\bigcup_{i=1}^m E_i$. (That is, uniformity of convergence is preserved under finite unions.)

Then you have $K\subseteq E_1\cup E_2$ where $E_1$ is the closed interval with endpoints $0,m$ and $E_2$ is the closed interval with endpoints $0,M$.

---

Aside: I can't figure out if the statement remains true in the complex plane.

Comment: I proved some time ago that function converges uniformly on finite unions.